# How to hide the Retention Warning in Office Documents

Tags: information-management, office, expiration

I'd like to know how I can hide (or disable) the retention warning that appears when somebody *downloads* a Microsoft Office document via Sharepoint, which is about to expire in the near future.
People in my company get confused by it.
In other words: When File X gets copied to a local hard drive, the expiration date of the new (copied file) needs to be reset.
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

i think what your looking for is irm, Information Rights Managment:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545608(v=office.14).aspx

also

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh545607(v=office.14).aspx

for you its called retention:

the setup can be found on **central admin** within **security** under **information policy** and click on **Configure Information Management Policy**

but for the list/library in question you need to goto list/library **settings**, under **Permissions and Management** click on **Information management policy settings** and click on **document**, within there you should see some options, check to see that **Enable Retention** is unchecked!

**EDIT**

LOL I get you ;) the retention I understand is shown in office but regardless its been encapsulated via sharepoint xaml i belive to show that warning!

to remove it do the following:

goto **central admin** -> click on **security** and under **information policy** and click on **Configure Information Management Policy** now click on **Retention**, you should see two radio buttons:

> Available for use in new site and list policies.

and

> Decommissioned: Unavailable to new site and list policies, but still
>   available in existing policies that use it.

by default `Available for use in new site and list policies`. is already selected. You want to select `Decommissioned: Unavailable to new site and list policies, but still available in existing policies that use it.` click ok and your all setup!

Comment: FYI: Retention must not be disabled. Only the warning in MS Office documents needs to be hidden.

Comment: retention by default is unchecked not disabled!

Comment: I'm afraid you don't understand my concern.
Let me be more specific:

Comment: just ammended my answer

Comment: In our company we enabled retention, because files NEED to expire.  
But when colleagues download a file to their personal hard drives the message "Warning: This files will be deleted in xy days" irritates them, so we just want to deactivate/hide/disable/whatever this message (ONLY AFTER the file is copied). The original file doesn't need to be changed. The warning kinda sticks to the file, which we don't want.